# Encrypt data changed when its saved into cookie, `+` turns into `%2B`?

Tags: php

```
 base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));

   encrypt data - //AHT+GFkX2opXrPyZZ2fQerLDgspBn2tgA4107wrSrOg=
   Cookie -       //AHT%2BGFkX2opXrPyZZ2fQerLDgspBn2tgA4107wrSrOg%3D
```

I have an encryption encrypt remember me user's id.

however the cookie become different after encrypt. because html code.

`+` become `%2B`, `=` become `%3D`

i need to decrypt the data

is anyway to solve this?

Comment: `urldecode()` the cookie value.

Comment: Why not use PHP's session functions? Encryption is hard to get right. You shouldn't use the same IV (`md5(md5($key))` in this case) more than once, and you need a message authentication code (such as HMAC-SHA-256, which can be generated by `hash_hmac()`) to ensure data integrity. According to http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38942/how-to-protect-against-padding-oracle-attacks , the MAC should be generated after encryption and checked before decryption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `urldecode($_COOKIE['name_of_cookie'])` in PHP to decode the string back to the original cookie value.

Here is more info on URL encoding and how to & when to use it.
http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/url_encoding.htm

The official docs (PHP Manual): http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: tempted to downvote because of the source. the PHP manual would be a much better source rather than about.com

Comment: no big deal. Just sayin, I wouldn't have down-voted anyway. I like the table that about.com has